# Ejabberd external autorization with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I am developing ejabberd external authorization with ejabberd but it does not seem to work

I used **ejabberd-aut**h npm module and set ejabberd.yml as follows

```
auth_method: external
extauth_program: "node ~/ejabberd-auth/index.js"
```

but it does not work as expected. I see no response in my ejavverd log file.

I also tried using **ejabberd_http_auth** module for using http authorization for ejabberd and build a rest interface for it using express but don't see any requests forwarded to ejabberd in logs and authentication does not work. I used following configuration for http authentication:

```
auth_method: http
auth_opts:
  host: "http://localhost:9095"
  connection_pool_size: 10
  connection_opts: []
  basic_auth: ""
  path_prefix: "/"
```

Can anyone guide me what i am doing wrong here?